# Dash Table мульти-фильтрация

Tags: table, dash

Имею подобный код с формированием таблицы и фильтрацией из выпадающих списков,

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/chriddyp/'
    'c78bf172206ce24f77d6363a2d754b59/raw/'
    'c353e8ef842413cae56ae3920b8fd78468aa4cb2/'
    'usa-agricultural-exports-2011.csv')



def generate_table(dataframe, max_rows=10):
    return html.Table(
        # Header
        [html.Tr([html.Th(col) for col in dataframe.columns])] +

        # Body
        [html.Tr([
            html.Td(dataframe.iloc[i][col]) for col in dataframe.columns
        ]) for i in range(min(len(dataframe), max_rows))]
    )


app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[

    dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown', options=[
        {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df.state.unique()
    ], multi=True, placeholder='Filter by state...'),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown1', options=[
        {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df.corn.unique()
    ], multi=True, placeholder='Filter by corn...'),
    dcc.Dropdown(options=[
        {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df.wheat.unique()
    ], multi=True, placeholder='Filter by wheat...'),

    html.Div(id='table-container', style={"margin": "20px"})
], style={"margin": "100px"})


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('table-container', 'children'),
    dash.dependencies.Input('dropdown', 'value'),
    dash.dependencies.Input('dropdown1', 'value'))
def display_table(dropdown_value, dropdown_value1):

    if dropdown_value is None and dropdown_value1 is None:
        return generate_table(df)
    if dropdown_value is not None and dropdown_value1 is not None:
        dff = df.loc[(df.state.str.contains('|'.join(dropdown_value))) & (df.corn.str.contains('|'.join(dropdown_value1)))]
        return generate_table(dff)
    if dropdown_value is not None:
        dff = df.loc[df.state.str.contains('|'.join(dropdown_value))]
        return generate_table(dff)
    if dropdown_value1 is not None:
        dff = df.loc[df.corn.str.contains('|'.join(dropdown_value1))]
        return generate_table(dff)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

при добавление фильтрации по колонке `corn` сталкиваюсь с ошибкой "AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!"
Просьба, подсказать, как решить ее в данном случае? также, хотелось спросить, возможно есть другой способ подобной фильтрации без громоздких конструкций с if?

Answer (score 0):

вроде нашел решения на первый вопрос,
переписав функцию к следующему формату,

```
def display_table(dropdown_value, dropdown_value1):

    if dropdown_value is None and dropdown_value1 is None:
        return generate_tb(df)
    if dropdown_value is not None and dropdown_value1 is not None:
        dff = df.loc[(df.state.astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(str(v) for v in dropdown_value))) &
                     (df.corn.astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(str(v) for v in dropdown_value1)))]
        return generate_tb(dff)
    if dropdown_value is not None:
        dff = df.loc[df.state.astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(str(v) for v in dropdown_value))]
        return generate_tb(dff)
    if dropdown_value1 is not None:
        dff = df.loc[df.corn.astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(str(v) for v in dropdown_value1))]
        return generate_tb(dff)
```

по второму, можете подсказать можно ли как то сократить конструкцию с if если будут добавляться новые фильтры столбцов?
Спасибо!